# What exactly were those 808X computers that would switch to 80386 upon Ctrl-Alt-Del?

Tags: 8080, 80386

A while ago I've been told that some generic-brand PC, (yet packed on an IBM5150 case) had the ability to become a 80386 upon pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del (warm reboot) ?

I guess there might have been (for sure) another processor in them but I've been unable to find details online about these mid-80's beasts.

**EDIT**

[Some information about a similar concept in a September '86 magazine](https://books.google.fr/books?id=vcqI6sY2e-kC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=reboot%208088%20ctrl%20alt%20del%20turbo%20mode&source=bl&ots=5Yh9FXtsI9&sig=unxCsvv9HvJxNwPPMrF7ElhnJyQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKqoKPotjOAhVElxoKHcvJA9AQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=reboot%208088%20ctrl%20alt%20del%20turbo%20mode&f=false)

[Another thing from April '87](https://books.google.fr/books?id=EjwEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=reboot%208088%20ctrl%20alt%20del%20turbo%20mode&source=bl&ots=sdqNChlshQ&sig=Gv831_brOSSeCgdnBCCYuHBBW_k&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKqoKPotjOAhVElxoKHcvJA9AQ6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q=reboot%208088%20ctrl%20alt%20del%20turbo%20mode&f=false)

[Some Linux stuff about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP+</kbd>](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-8.html)

[But as far as I remember it was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and there was no turbo button on the machine.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_button)

A guess is that it's what we used to call *IBM PC* ***and compatibles*** back in the time (a clone) :)

Comment: It could have been a real / protected mode confusion.

Comment: Possibly, I had access to this PC when I was ~6 years ... couldn't really figure it out at the time. One of the things I do remember though, was that some hippie came up home, de-soldered a few ceramic capacitors because supposedly it would run better without them :)

Comment: I actually have a Breakthru 286-12 board (the board reviewed in your second link), but speed is toggled using a switch on the expansion card (which ends up on the back of the PC), not using software.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Keypad + and - was used in Linux to switch video modes by the driver, and had no relation to any hardware. Apparently on a few motherboards this key combination also enabled/disabled turbo mode (faster clock), which was normally done by some extra front panel button, but again this doesn't mean a processor "switch" to 80386, nor a reboot.

Comment: @StephenKitt it's interesting how with 'Breakthru 286-12' keywords I do find much more literature online about this era :)

Comment: @dirkt from what I understand basically these were 286/386 but they would start without turbo or real mode, i.e. BIOS has been customized by the manufacturer somehow, but that's a just a guess.

Comment: @Aybe: PCs with "turbo" buttons were quite common (I used some of them). Wikipedia has a [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_button). They were used from 8086 CPUs till early Pentium, and just changed the clock frequency, nothing else (what today you'd call "overclocking"). It has nothing to do with "real mode" or "protected mode".

Comment: Yes I know, I had a 486 actually ;) Another thing comes to my mind, on old PCs, if you did disable cache in BIOS it would run very slowly :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you describe sounds like the [PC Elevator](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uj0EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=80386%20accelerator&source=bl&ots=EIq0io5WEY&sig=PVIJ9o5F0tAt9Q51MhzuLQEq9fU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTjNvPltnOAhVYwGMKHZHoBHMQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=80386%20accelerator&f=false):

> The PC Elevator 386 is a coprocessor-type accelerator board. The system's native CPU remains available for any programs that are sensitive to speed or timing. Software commands (Up for the faster 386 mode and Down for the slower speed) make speed selection simple. Initial startup via the Up command requires system rebooting.